# How to debug system logcat when android os is hang out

Tags: android, debugging, operating-system, android-source

I build a custom aosp 7.1 rc4 for my x64 device, it worked quite well.
Then I want to make some changes in wifi module and build the wifi-service by:

```
cd ~/aosp
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch 8
cd ~/aosp/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/service
mma
```

after that I copy the wpa_supplicant, libwifi-service.so wifi-service.jar and wifi-service.odex to the device and rebooting it.
The os is hang out in the android starting screen.

How could I read the system logcat in this situation?

Comment: Did you try asking the guys at xda? They are experts at this stuff. I'm not sure if they will help , though!

Comment: @PrinceAli thanks for your recommendation. I will try this.